# Does everybody have to agree on SO_REUSEADDR?

Tags: sockets, tcp

All discussion I've seen on `SO_REUSEADDR` assumes that it's the same program creating and binding to a TCP socket on a known port.

I have two different programs using the same port, and I'm curious about how the mechanism works -- in order for program 2 to allocate a port program 1 has just closed, do they both have to specify `SO_REUSEADDR` after they create the socket?

Or is it enough for one of them? If so, the one taking the socket first or the one trying to open it afterwards, when it's lingering in TIME_WAIT state?

Here's a small example in Python to hopefully make the case clearer;

```
# one.py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("", 5050)) # Assuming 5050 is available
sys.exit(1)        # Assuming s enters TIME_WAIT

# two.py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("", 5050))
s.listen()
```

Think of one.py and two.py as two separate codebases.

Does both one.py and two.py need to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option in order for two.py to tolerate a lingering TIME_WAIT socket from one.py?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml
I guess all your programs should use SO_REUSEADRR.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uses of SO_REUSEADDR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577885/uses-of-so-reuseaddr)

Comment: @JeremyD -- thanks! I take that to mean that only the second program needs SO_REUSEADDR? It's not entirely clear to me still.

Comment: @VladLazarenko -- I don't think so. I think I understand what SO_REUSEADDR is for, I'm asking if multiple parties need to agree for it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question. I believe that **on Linux** you have to specify `SO_REUSEADDR` **ONLY** in the program that wants to reuse the port. Very simple. On Microsoft Windows however, this is a different story. Microsoft has [a page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that covers SO_REUSEADDR and related features.

Comment: Thanks, that MSDN hint was really thorough. I understand more of the background for `SO_REUSEADDR` now, even though I didn't see any mention of the socket state there. Maybe this comes down to empirical testing of different implementations.

Comment: Also, thanks for bringing up portability concerns, I never mentioned I needed a consistent strategy for both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that yes, all programs using the same port should use `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Because the timeout for reusing ports is a kernel thing.

(but I may be wrong).

Comment: Thanks! But I can't quite follow your logic... Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The system call behind listening sockets is `bind()`, and you cannot bind to the same port on the same address(es) at the same time: the OS forbids that. `SO_REUSEADDR` tells that other sockets may listen after the program exits. But as long as it has not exited, it is proprietary of this port.

Comment: Yes, this makes more sense after your edit :-). But this is not what I'm asking -- the question is if both programs need to specify SO_REUSEADDR in order for program 2, after program 1 has closed its socket, to be able to open a socket on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack("ii", 1, 0))
```

You can abruptly terminate the TIME_WAIT state of TCP negotiation flow by setting SO_LINGER socket option to zero.

Good when you allow two states, ESTABLISHED or nothing.