# Why does tomcat receive request when multiple processes listen to the port?

Tags: java, apache, sockets, tomcat, tomcat7

I recently found out about `SO_REUSEADDR` on windows; and that tomcat uses this by [default](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Java_TCP_socket_attributes).

I did a small test to find out what happens when another process is also listening to the same port. The other process in my case was `netcat`. The results were surprising:

- Irrespective of whether I start `nc` (`netcat`) first or `tomcat`, the response if from tomcat
- If I stop tomcat with its `bin/tomcat.bat` it also kills the `nc` process
- If I stop tomcat by killing the process then nc is able to respond to the next connection

**What magic is this?** How is tomcat always able to grab incoming request? Is this (tomcat will serve all connections even if other processes are listening) guaranteed behavior? I cannot imagine how it can be guaranteed but thought to ask.

Comment: It's the magic of whatever Windows does when allowing processes to share TCP ports. I haven't been able to find the semantics exactly defined anywhere in MSDN, only statements that it is possible. The purpose also escapees me.

Comment: @EJP I liked this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/577905/18573) regarding its purpose.

Comment: That's the purpose of SO_REUSEADDR. It isn't the purpose of allowing multiple processes to share the same port on Windows. Unix etc. don't allow it. The point escapes me.

Comment: @EJP You mean [this thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Have you read the [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) documentation?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I had not read it immediately before posting the question but I have done that now. I am afraid I am not able to figure out an answer from that, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch There isn't a word about port sharing in the ServerSocket documentation. It is a Windows feature.

Comment: @BrianRoach Thanks but I don't really see anything there that defines the semantics that apply in the OP's situation. It's a lower level thing that applies to SO_REUSEADDR on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to answer this from the question that user nos asked in response to my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031229/how-to-disable-so-reuseaddr-in-tomcat?noredirect=1#comment31617225_21031229) question.

I realized that since I was using `wget http://localhost:8080` in my test, it was using `IPv6` which only tomcat was listening on.

When I changed it to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` I saw completely different behavior.