# Thread UDP Socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

I'm trying to make a multi threading udp server with python.

Here is what I am doing :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:Utf-8 -*-

import sys
import socket
from thread import start_new_thread


class Broker():
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.s.bind((ip, port))
        self.listclients = []

def listenMod(b):
    dic = {}
    msg, ip = b.s.recvfrom(1024)
    dic[msg] = ip
    b.listclients.append(dic)
    print msg, " is connected."


def broker(arg):
    try:
        b = Broker(arg[2], int(arg[3]))
        start_new_thread(listenMod, (b, ))

    except Exception, e:
        print e
        sys.exit(-1)


def client(arg):
    try:
        pass
    except:
        pass

def usage():
    print "usage ./udps.py <-b|-c> <args>"
    print "-b\tserver mode\n\t<args>: host port"
    sys.exit()

def main():
    i = 1
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        while i < len(sys.argv):
            if sys.argv[1] == "-b":
                broker(sys.argv)
            elif sys.argv[1] == "-c":
                pass
            else:
                usage()
    else:
        usage()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It always prints "[Errno 48] Address already in use"

I'm using this because I would like to be able do to some special things with my clients but also be able to connect new clients at the same time.

Comment: Do you call `broker()` multiple times? You can't bind a socket to one single port multiple times… Maybe you show some more code, related to the usage of `broker()`.

Comment: no i don't.
Actually it works if i don't use :

start_new_thread(listenMod, (b, ))

but just : 
listenMod(b)

Comment: Which line of your code fails?  Can you provide a full working example program?

Comment: You have to show how this class is being used. You can't bind to the same port number twice - only one socket can be bound to a port.

Comment: start_new_thread(listenMod, (b, )) makes my code failed.
I call my class constructor once.

Comment: Actually it's not my own function [link]https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html

Comment: Did it work the first time you ran the program?

Comment: not at all.
It works if I replace `start_new_thread(listenMod, (b, )` by `listenMod(b)`

Comment: Just provide a working reproducible example, which everyone can launch.

Comment: `broker(sys.argv)` is not a working example… There are imports missing and syntax errors in your code.

Comment: This question will be flagged if the OP fails to provide a working example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited my code, it should be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `SO_REUSEADDR`. There are [legitimate uses of `SO_REUSEADDR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577885/uses-of-so-reuseaddr), but in most simple cases it is not useful, and it hides the real problem. Feel free to re-add it if needed, but only when your program works without it.

Your problem here is in your `main`. You are looping on the number of arguments, but never increment `i`, so it loops infinitely. Also you are always testing `argv[1]`. If there are 4 arguments, and the 2nd is '-b', you will call `broker()` 4 times, which will obviously not work. Also, note that if your loop ends and the main exit, your program will terminate immediately, so you should at least add a `while(True): sleep(5)` at the end, but it's not a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use SO_REUSEADDR cause my code is designed to make an UDP Hole Punching prototype.

Comment: @ZeenaZeek Hole punching doesn't require SO_REUSEADDR. But well, if you need it for your implementation it's not a problem. SO_REUSEADDR isn't bad in itself, just keep in mind that it can hide potential problems.