# Can more than 1 app listen on same Udp Port 514

Tags: c#, udp

I am able to listen on Udp port 514 using below code,

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient
        {
            ExclusiveAddressUse = false
        };
        IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514);

        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;

        client.Client.Bind(localEp);

        IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.0.0.222");
        client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);

        Console.WriteLine("Listening this will never quit so you will need to ctrl-c it");

        while (true)
        {
            Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);
            string strData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine(strData);
        }
```

When I m trying to open any 3rd party application like "Visual Syslog Server" which is also listening on same Udp port 514, then my application won't show any results, neither I am getting any error.

Some suggestion to use Multicast, I tried in above code, but not working.

Is there any thing I am missing or how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You have enabled address reusing option, so it is acceptable to having more than one application listening on same port. What do you expect?

Comment: The `SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress` only prevents an error when you reuse a port # still in use. It does _not_ allow two different sockets to both receive the same data. Frankly, it's an option that anyone who is not an expert in socket programming simply should not use. Whether you'll receive data or not is dependent on factors outside your control. If your program doesn't own all the sockets using that address, you simply cannot guarantee you'll see all the data sent to that address.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621(v=vs.85).aspx): _"Once the second socket has successfully bound, the behavior for all sockets bound to that port is indeterminate"_. Note that the exception is for multicast sockets, where all sockets are assured of receiving data. See marked duplicate for the same basic answer and additional commentary. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577885/uses-of-so-reuseaddr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t

Comment: This means that if more than one application listening on same port, only one application will get data, Right?

Comment: _"This means that if more than one application listening on same port, only one application will get data"_ -- no. The word "indeterminate" means that what will happen is not defined. The OS is free to do whatever it wants. In practice, usually it means only one socket will get the data. But it's possible for none to get the data, some to get the data, all to get the data (if there are more than two), etc. If not knowing whether you're going to get the data or not is not okay in your scenario, don't use `ReuseAddress`. Or, frankly, UDP for that matter.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Then whats need to do so that -- all  get the data?

Comment: Actually your current code (if remove `JoinMulticastGroup` part) should happily receive broadcast messages. Try running two instances of this application (without Syslog server), then send broadcast UDP (to "192.168.1.255" or whatever broardcast address is for your particular network) and you will see they both will receive it. Or you need to receive unicast messages this way?

Comment: Thanks @Evk, Could you please explain --  send broadcast UDP (to "192.168.1.255" or whatever broardcast address is for your particular network)

Comment: Well, `new UdpClient().Send(stuff, stuff.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255"), 514)` is roughly what I mean (broardcast address depends on your network, I cannot tell what it is in your particular case). How are you sending udp messages now? Or if that's not you - maybe you have information about that still.

Comment: Thanks, It's showing up message into both instance.

Comment: this means only broadcasted message only able to show in 2 different application?

Comment: Broadcast and multicast messages should work fine, but unicast (like this: `new UpdClient().Send(stuff, stuff.Length, IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"), 514)`) will not. But in general, answer to question in your title is yes - multiple apps can bind and listen to the same udp port, as you see yourself now.

Comment: By the way, @PeterDuniho I don't see how it's duplicate for that question. Question you marked is about _one_ UdpClient  did not receive UDP messages, and the reason turned out to be windows firewall.

Comment: @Evk: the pertinent passage from the answer in the marked duplicate: _"Unless you're using broadcast or multi-cast, only one of the UDP listeners on that port will get the message"_. Fact is, both questions are too broad for Stack Overflow, lack good [mcve], and are potentially not even about programming (the other could have been closed as _"Questions on...networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic"_). But to the extent that the OP here needs to understand that reusing the address does not assure delivery of data, the other question's answer suffices.