# Mutlcast UDP: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: .net, sockets, udpclient

I am trying to use UDPClient to listen for multicast IP (UDP port 3000) packets.

When I do have the sender program running (which also listens to that port) then I get the following error on line UdpClient listener =  ...

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'
```

However, if it is not running, I don't get that error, but the program locks on waiting for the packets to arrive.

The full text of the program is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vtunnel
{
    public class UDPListener
    {
        private const int listenPort = 3000;
        private const string multicastIP = "239.0.0.0";
        private const string myIP = "10.4.30.239";

        public static void StartListener() { 
            bool done = false;
            IPAddress listenAddress;
            IPAddress myAddress;

            IPAddress.TryParse(multicastIP, out listenAddress);
            UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(listenAddress, listenPort);

            try
            {
                while (!done)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for multicast");
                    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

                    Console.WriteLine("Received multicast from {0} :\n {1}\n",
                        groupEP.ToString(),
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UDPListener.StartListener();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you'll need to set SO_REUSEADDR flag to the socket before it gets binded.

```
Dim listener As New UdpClient()
listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
listener.Client.Bind(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort))
listener.JoinMulticastGroup(listenAddress)
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/577905/1486185

http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/

Comment: It is a DIS simulation, I.e. - something like a game engine. It both sends and receives multicast packets from peer engines. My c# program I am writing here is going to tap into the packet stream and send copies to a vpn address. So far I am stuck on just listening for the packets.

Comment: I know that you can have two peer engines on the same node. And they can both be doing send and receive on the same port.

Comment: I've rewrited the answer. I didn't realized that multicast part. Even when your question was perfectly clear about it :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes. this works great. Now I want to update the receive to be async so that it can do a send